# What apps provide annotated steps of calculations?

Tags: signal-processing

I have mathematical formulas that I need to calculate and my question is:

What apps provide a calculation’s steps with explanations?

In `Wolfram Alpha` and `Symbolab`, I'm getting the issue as:

[image]

> No Steps: Steps are currently not supported for this problem -
> Symbolab

[image]
or simply no results related to it.

To clarify, I'm not asking about how to do it or how easy it is. I'm asking what resources can be used and how they could be helpful in this use case.